# Proper way to optimize the input in TensorFlow for visualization

Tags: tensorflow, visualization

I have trained a model in TensorFlow and now I would like to visualize which inputs maximally activate an output. I'd like to know what the cleanest way to do this is.

I had thought to do this by creating a trainable input variable which I can assign once per run. Then by using an appropriate loss function and using an optimizer with a var_list containing just this input variable I would update this input variable until convergence. i.e.

```
trainable_input = tf.get_variable(
    'trainable_input',
    shape=data_op.get_shape(),
    dtype=data_op.dtype,
    initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    trainable=True,
    collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
trainable_input_assign_op = tf.assign(trainable_input, data_op)
data_op = trainable_input

# ... run the rest of the graph building code here, now with a trainable input

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
# loss_op is defined on one of the outputs
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, var_list=[trainable_input])
```

However, when I do this I run into issues. If I try to restore the pre-trained graph using a Supervisor, then it naturally complains that the new variables created by the AdamOptimizer do not exist in the graph I'm trying to restore. I can remedy this by using get_slots to get the variables the AdamOptimizer creates and manually adding those variables to the tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES collection, but it feels pretty hacky and I'm not sure what the consequences of this would be. I can also exclude those variables explicitly from the Saver that is passed to the Supervisor without adding them to the tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES collection, but then I get an exception that they do not get properly initialized by the Supervisor:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 973, in managed_session
self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 801, in stop
stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 386, in join
six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 962, in managed_session
start_standard_services=start_standard_services)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 719, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 280, in prepare_session
self._local_init_op, msg))
RuntimeError: Init operations did not make model ready.  Init op: init, init fn: None, local_init_op: name: "group_deps_5"
op: "NoOp"
input: "^init_1"
input: "^init_all_tables"
, error: Variables not initialized: trainable_input/trainable_input/Adam, trainable_input/trainable_input/Adam_1
```

I'm not really sure why these variables are not getting initialized since I have used that technique before to exclude some variables from the restore process (GLOBAL and LOCAL) and they seem to get initialized as expected.

In short, my question is whether there is a simple way to add an optimizer to the graph and do a checkpoint restore (where the checkpoint does not contain the optimizer variables) without having to muck around with the internals of the optimizer. If that's not possible, then is there any downside to just adding the optimizer variables to the LOCAL_VARIABLES collection?

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurs when I use slim library. In fact, the `slim.learning.train()` uses `tf.train.Supervisor` inside. I hope my answer on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13342) may help your Supervisor problem.

I have the same problem with you. I solve it by doing following two steps.

#### 1. pass the parameter `saver` to `slim.learning.train()`

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.train_dir)
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=optimistic_restore_vars(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path) if ckpt else None)
```

where function [optimistic_restore_vars](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/312) is defined as

```
def optimistic_restore_vars(model_checkpoint_path):
    reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(model_checkpoint_path)
    saved_shapes = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
    var_names = sorted([(var.name, var.name.split(':')[0]) for var in tf.global_variables() if var.name.split(':')[0] in saved_shapes])
    restore_vars = []
    name2var = dict(zip(map(lambda x:x.name.split(':')[0], f.global_variables()), tf.global_variables()))
    with tf.variable_scope('', reuse=True):
        for var_name, saved_var_name in var_names:
            curr_var = name2var[saved_var_name]
            var_shape = curr_var.get_shape().as_list()
            if var_shape == saved_shapes[saved_var_name]:
                restore_vars.append(curr_var)
    return restore_vars
```

```

#### 2. pass the parameter `local_init_op` to `slim.learning.train()` to initialize the added new variables

```
local_init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

#### In last, the code should look like this

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.train_dir)
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=optimistic_restore_vars ckpt.model_checkpoint_path) if ckpt else None)
local_init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

###########################
# Kicks off the training. #
###########################
learning.train(
    train_tensor,
    saver=saver,
    local_init_op=local_init_op,
    logdir=FLAGS.train_dir,
    master=FLAGS.master,
    is_chief=(FLAGS.task == 0),
    init_fn=_get_init_fn(),
    summary_op=summary_op,
    number_of_steps=FLAGS.max_number_of_steps,
    log_every_n_steps=FLAGS.log_every_n_steps,
    save_summaries_secs=FLAGS.save_summaries_secs,
    save_interval_secs=FLAGS.save_interval_secs,
    sync_optimizer=optimizer if FLAGS.sync_replicas else None
)
```